# Does a larger pressure chamber fail easier at the same pressure?

Tags: pressure

Let's say you pump ten psi into a box with one inch unit length, and ten psi into a cuboid with two inches length, there is a force of ten pound on the first wall, but wouldn't the second chamber have ten pounds for each on inch length? = twenty pounds for the total length... so if I had to make super high pressure for some reason, and was like welding plate steel of a given thickness for the reaction chamber, wouldn't smaller be safer?

Comment: A look at the Wikipedia article on [pressure vessels](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_vessel) will confirm this.

Comment: The "given thickness" is important here.  Consider that if you scale up the walls while leaving thickness the same, how that might effect the strength of any given point in the material.

Comment: @Chemomechanics I skimmed through that, and came back to it several times. Haven't done a total study. But I cant see a answer to my question. Do you have any tips as to where there to read / what to read?

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the equations for hoop and longitudinal stress, each of which scale up with the container size. Maury also notes this in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

> if I had to make super high pressure for some reason, and was like
>   welding plate steel of a given thickness for the reaction chamber,
>   wouldn't smaller be safer

Yes.

Theoretically, the limit is the tension limit of the container material. The tension in that material goes up with size and pressure, and down with wall thickness; T = pr/t, where T is the hoop tension, p is the pressure, r is the radius, and t is the thickness of the material.

In practice, limits tend to be practical; the weakest part of a weld is the weakest part of the container.